# Retain duplicates in the given list using Stream API

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream, iteration

I want to find the duplicates in a set of identifier objects.

Example:

1. NE , SN1
2. NE , SN
3. NE1 , SN
4. NE , SN1

The result should be NE, SN1 in the List.

```
class Identifier {

 String reference;//NE

 String number;//SN1

 String digiId; //Not used for duplicate identification 

//getters and setters
}

public static List<Identifier> getDuplicates(List<Identifier> list) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> noOfDupliactes = list.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Identifier::getReference,Collectors.groupingBy(Identifier::getNumber, Collectors.counting())));

**//How to process noOfDupliactes in Java8 using stream to get the List<Identifier>?**

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two `Identifier` objects with `NE, SN1` in your original list. Which one should be in the result list?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `equals/hashCode` of the **Identifier** doesn't match your requirements and cant be changed.

From your example, I understood that you want to get one representative for each duplicate combination of `number` and `reference`.

**The first** approach utilizes streams. Firstly it creates a map, filters out buckets with a single value, peeks one element from every bucket with duplicates, and collects to List.

```
    public static List<Identifier> getDuplicates(List<Identifier> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(IdWrapper::new))
                .values().stream()
                .filter(identifiers -> identifiers.size() > 1)
                .map(identifiers -> identifiers.stream().findAny().orElseThrow())
                .toList();
    }
```

For this solution record **IdWrapper** can be implemented like this:

```
    record IdWrapper(String reference, String number) {
        IdWrapper(final Identifier identifier) {
            this(identifier.reference, identifier.number);
        }
    }
```

**The second** approach requires `a single traversal over the given list`.

Every element of the list is checked against the `set`, if an element gets rejected by the `set` that means it's duplicate.

```
    public static List<Identifier> getDuplicates(List<Identifier> list) {
        Set<IdWrapper> wrappers = new HashSet<>();
        Set<IdWrapper> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
        for (Identifier id: list) {
            IdWrapper wrapper = new IdWrapper(id);
            if (!wrappers.add(wrapper)) {
                duplicates.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
        return unwrap(duplicates);
    }
```

```
    private static List<Identifier> unwrap(Collection<IdWrapper> duplicates) {
        return duplicates.stream()
                .map(IdWrapper::getId)
                .toList(); // for Java 16 and above == collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
```

Record **IdWrapper** (could be implemented as a class if you are using `Java 15` or earlier) is used to establish uniqueness (i.e. provide `equals` and `hashCode`) based on the `number` and `reference` of the **Identifier** object.

```
    record IdWrapper(Identifier id) {

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            IdWrapper other = (IdWrapper) o;
            return this.id.reference.equals(other.id.reference) && this.id.number.equals(other.id.number);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.id.reference, this.id.number);
        }
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Identifier> ids = List.of(
                new Identifier("NE" , "SN1"),
                new Identifier("NE" , "SN"),
                new Identifier("NE1" , "SN"),
                new Identifier("NE" , "SN1")
        );

        System.out.println(getDuplicates(ids));
    }
```

**output** (identical for both versions of `getDuplicates()`)

```
    [Identifier{reference='NE', number='SN1'}]
```

Comment: Nice - your record could be improved though to take advantage of the built-in mechanisms for equals and hashCode:
`record IdWrapper(String reference, String number) { IdWrapper(final Identifier identifier) { this(identifier.reference, identifier.number); }}`

Comment: @AndreasBerheimBrudin good point, that will play well with the first solution. The second approach requires a reference to the Identifier object this lite-weight version will not be sufficient.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I am leaving my answer deleted.  I think only one indication of a duplicate is required.  I could solve this by using another `TreeSet` for dups but I didn't really like the overhead of the sorting before and I wouldn't want to repeat that again.   If a regular `HashSet` would take a comparator or some way of substituting a different equals and hashCode it would be a reasonable solution.  Your idea of a wrapper class solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your expected output correctly, that should work:

```
public static List<Identifier> getDuplicates(List<Identifier> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is just one of the standard methods to get a list of duplicates in a list.

Just make sure to add proper .equals and .hashCode methods in your code, for example similar to this (but with your getters)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Identifier that = (Identifier) o;
    return Objects.equals(reference, that.reference) && Objects.equals(number, that.number);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(reference, number);
}
```

Comment: I missed a point in my question. Class Identifier is having one more field String digiId. But I want to find the duplicates based on reference and number only.